# Django вызов функции из одной view в другую view

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.
У меня в одном приложении есть два файла `view` Назовем их `view1` и `view2`
В `view1` есть функция `appcard` она импортируется в `view2`:

```
from app.view1 import appcard
```

Выдает ошибку:

> cannot import name appcard

Comment: проверьте, нет ли у вас во view1 импорта из view2